# Block incoming sms android using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an android application about Block incoming Sms. My problem is when I built my app and tested. I could not block any sms. 
Here my code :

My Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.dev.autosms.ReceiveSms"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Here is my receiveSms.java :

```
public class ReceiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       abortBroadcast();
      }

}
```

Could you help me? 
Thank all!

Comment: What is your android version? This won't work since Kitkat. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805535/how-to-prevent-sms-going-to-inbox-in-android-kitkat

Comment: my device on Android 5.0 . OMG. So, How to solved this problem?

Comment: The only way is to request the user to switch to your app as the default SMS receiver (and you would provide the functionality of an SMS app).  Or write an app that requires root (which is another story).